# Проблемы с переходом между сценами Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня возникла проблема: при работе с переходами с одной сцены на другую возникла проблема: когда по специальной кнопке перехожу с одной сцены на другую, то на ней ломается базовый шейдер (ничего, что связано с шейдерами не накатывал дополнительно, разве что угол наклона встроенного солнца разный на обеих сценах), текстуры перестают нормально отображаться со всех сторон, т.е. в некоторых местах они становятся чёрными, плюс при переходе между сценами unity на некоторое время зависает. Подскажите, что не так в коде? Может быть чего-то упустил?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Single_player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button PlayInSelectedWorldButton; // Привязанная кнопка для перехода между сценами

    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void PlayInSelectedWorld() // Функция для перехода на другую сцену
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        PlayInSelectedWorldButton.onClick.AddListener(PlayInSelectedWorld);
    }


}
```

Comment: `PlayInSelectedWorldButton.onClick.AddListener(PlayInSelectedWorld);` перенесите в `Start()`, а из `Update()` удалите, и всё заработает. Вы каждый кадр подписываетесь на событие нажатия на кнопку, то есть если 60 кадров в секунду, то 60 раз в секунду, например вы нажимаете на кнопку через 10 секунд, после начала работы скрипта, это значит что метод `PlayInSelectedWorld` будет вызван 600 раз.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Но что делать со странной работой рендера? Если я непосредственно игровую сцену запущу, то всё нормально а когда вызываю её при помощи вышеупомянутого скрипта, то происходят абсолютные затемнения неосвещённых солнцем поверхностей, а так же небольшое пожелтение освещённых текстур